# Threaded program and structs changing values to trash

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, return-value

I am writing a test program at this point to get a base down but when I run this it is feeding trash values into my struct.

If this is a bit incomplete I apologize, I've been working with this, searching the net for hours and everything I'm doing seems to be correct however I am getting garbage inserted into some critical values when I pass them through the pthread_create function.

Thanks for any help!

## This code is giving me the following output:

main function running!

initial set of gWorkerid = 0

workerID = 319534848

Howdy Doody!

end sleep

gWorkerid is now trash value = -946297088

## I am expecting:

main function running!

initial set of gWorkerid = 0

workerID = 0

Howdy Doody!

end sleep

gWorkerid is now trash value = 0

```
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    #define MAX_CONN 3
    #define MAX_LINE 1000

    typedef struct worker_t
    {
        int id;
        int connection;
        pthread_t thread;
        int used;
    }WORKER_T;

    struct sockaddr_in gServ_addr;

    WORKER_T gWorker[MAX_CONN];
    char sendBuff[1025];

    // Thread function
    void * worker_proc(void *arg)
    {
        WORKER_T *me = (WORKER_T*) arg;

        printf("Howdy Doody!\n");

        return NULL;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        printf("main function running!\n");
        pthread_t threadTest;
        int i = 0;

        gWorker[i].id = i;
        printf("initial set of gWorkerid = %d\n", gWorker[i].id);
        gWorker[i].connection = i;
        gWorker[i].used = 1;
        pthread_create(&gWorker[i], NULL, worker_proc, &gWorker[i]);

        sleep(1);

        printf("end sleep\n");
        printf("gWorkerid is now trash value = %d\n", gWorker[i].id);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
pthread_create (&gWorker[i], NULL, worker_proc, &gWorker[i]);
```

should actually be:

```
pthread_create (&(gWorker[i].thread), NULL, worker_proc, &gWorker[i]);
```

That first parameter to `pthread_create()` is where to store the thread ID and, in the case of your code, it stores it at the start of the structure, overwriting `id`.

By passing the address of the thread ID part of the structure, `id` should be left untouched by `pthread_create()`.

Comment: The original code should not even compile, since the pointer type for the argument mismatches. Looks like yet another chance of GCC accepting badly-invalid code by default and thereby hiding beginners' errors from them.

Comment: Actually, @R.., I think that would just be a warning, I doubt it would stop compilation. But, even as a warning, it should at least be looked at.

Comment: There's certainly no *obligation* on a compiler to accept the code, since it contains a constraint violation. There is an obligation to issue a diagnostic. The high-quality approach to this diagnostic would be a fatal error. My complaint is that gcc accepts code like this which contains constraint violations which, if rejected, would reveal *definite errors* in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
pthread_create(&gWorker[i], NULL, worker_proc, &gWorker[i]);
```

to:

```
pthread_create(&(gWorker[i].thread), NULL, worker_proc, &gWorker[i]);
```

`pthread_create()` expects a pointer to a `pthread_t` as the first argument, which it then populates. In your case, `pthread_create` is populating over the top of your `WORKER_T` structure.